# Why my arrow function doesn't work when getting an specific element?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use an arrow function and I am getting an error when I attempt to assign a variable

```
let cardColor;
let fontColor;

let toggleSidebarInfo = () => {
    let colors;
    $('.client-director, .person-link, .card-picture').click((evt) => {
        employeeId = evt.target.id;
      ///// FOCUS ON THIS PART //////
        colors = $(this).hasClass('card-picture') ?
            (cardColor = $(this).next().css('backgroundColor'),
             fontColor = $(this).next().css('color')) :
            (cardColor = $(this).css('backgroundColor'),
             fontColor = $(this).css('color'));
     /////////////////////////
        compareId(employeeId);
    });
};
```

if I console log `cardColor` of `fontColor` I get undefined as I am doing

`.click((evt) => { . . . });`

but if I do it the regular way

`.click(function(evt) { . . . });`

then everything works properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Because you're referring to `this`? Just don't try to use an arrow function where it's not appropriate.

Comment: @Bergi so what should I use instead of `$(this)` ? I thought it was an special (this) feature of jQuery. Like a different kind of this applied to jQuery objects

Comment: While the simplest solution is to use the proper function type, you could also use `evt.currentTarget` to get the bound element. Though I wouldn't use the arrow function unless you specifically need the `this` of the outer lexical environment.

Comment: `$()` is a special jQuery function, `this` is context and comes from Javascript. If `this` isn't appropriate for your use case, `$()` won't give you what you expect, but you have to get `this` right first, which has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrow functions` will bind its `lexical scope` into it automatically, so in your case the `this` inside of event handler will not point the elements of event handler.

Using of `arrow functions` will make your `event binding` just like below,

```
$('.client-director, .person-link, .card-picture').click(function(evt){

}.bind(this));
```

Here during event binding,  using arrow functions is inappropriate. The best option is to go with normal anonymous function.

> Also note that you cannot override the scope bound by arrow function
>   in any manner.

Comment: so what should I use instead of `$(this)` ? I thought it was an special feature of jQuery

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer: We didn't say you should change `$(this)`, we said you should change back to `function`.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. Actually my code works only by putting function, if you put bind(this) at the end, it won't work.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer I said, arrow function would make your code like that. So do not use it in this context.